# How to access children of mainWindow for UI Automation in Xcode

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a structure in the mainWindow() of my application as follows:

[image]

Within the children directory of the UIAWindow near the top of the image, I am trying to access Item 1, where it is a UIAButton.

This structure is generated from

```
#import "tuneup/tuneup.js"

goAbout = function(target, app)
{
    UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();

};

test("go about", goAbout);
```

If I add `.button()` or `[1]` it raises an exception, so I cannot do something like so

```
...
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons().logElementTree();
```

What can I do to access the object within the children subdirectory of the UIAWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that button by adding `.buttons()[0]`. The

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons();
```

expression returns a javascript array (which has a 0 based indexing).

Here you can find a rather usable documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/UIAutomationRef.pdf

Anyway studying this plist is not the most convenient method to explore your object hierarchy. I prefer to check instruments output directy. (Or standard output, if you run instruments from command line.)

Answer (score 0):

That tree hierarchy ended up not meaning anything useful to me, and I ended up utilizing target methods to access the elements of my window. Cheers!